# Fourier transform of tf^2(t)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Do you think I'm doing it correctly?

Find Fourier transform of $t f^{2}(t)$

$\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{t f^{2}(t)\right\} e^{j \omega t} d t$

Using time multiplication of FT: $t^{n} f(t)=(j)^{n} \frac{d^{n}}{d \omega^{n}} F(\omega)$

assuming $g(t)=f^{2}(t)$

Therefore,
$\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\{\operatorname{tg}(t)\} e^{j \omega t} d t=j \frac{d}{d \omega^{n}} G(\omega)$
since $g(t)=f^{2}(t)$

using another FT property:
$f^{n}(t)=j^{n} \omega^{n} F(\omega)$

Therefore,
$G(\omega)=j^{2} \omega^{2} F(\omega)$

Finally,
$\mathscr{F}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{t f^{2}(t)\right\} e^{j \omega t} d t=j \frac{d}{d \omega^{n}} j^{2} \omega^{2} F(\omega)$

Comment: No, Fourier transform of $f^n$ is not $(j\omega)^n F$

Comment: Thank you! I've checked it carefully but the formula looks correct. The formula is from Schaum's mathematical handbook of formulas and tables, 2nd ed, page #192. Could you please let me know what's the correct version in your view?

Comment: In the title you say $t^2f^2$ but in the post you say $tf^2$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I'll try to fix the error in title.

Comment: Modulo some constant factor, the Fourier transform of $tf(t)^2$ is $\delta'*f*f=f'*f=f*f'=(f*f)'.$

Comment: Fixed the error in the title. Could you please check my attempt and see if I'm doing it correctly. I see that your suggested formula involves convolution but I'd prefer to use the FT properties and FT pairs to get the solution. Thanks.

Comment: You should check the property that LL 3.14 said again; what you said is still wrong. What is correct is
$$ f^{(n)}(t) \xrightarrow{FT} j^n\omega^n F(\omega)$$
$f^{(n)}$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$. $f^n$ is the product of $f$ with itself, $n$ times. $f^{(n)} \neq f^n$ in general

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks a lot. I stand corrected now. So, I'm supposed to use the variation of this FT property: $f_{1}(t) f_{2}(t) \stackrel{F T}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{2 \pi} F_{1}(\omega) * F_{2}(\omega)$? I think this is the variation I'm supposed to use: $f(t)^{2} \stackrel{F T}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \{F(\omega)\}^{2}$ . Could you please confirm if I'm proceeding correctly?

Comment: The $*$ means convolution. So no, its not right. The correct answer which can't be written in any simpler way (that I can see) is what md2perpe said, except that he should have written $\hat f$ or F instead of $f$ in the final formula. i.e.
$$ \mathscr F(t f^2) = j[ \mathscr F(f^2) ]' = j( \hat f * \hat f)' $$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Am I interpreting md2perpe's suggestion correctly? I think this is what was said: $tf(t)^{2} \stackrel{F T}{\longrightarrow} = \frac{d}{d \omega} (F(\omega) * F(\omega))$. Assuming I'm interpreting it correctly, how do I find some source for this pair online? I couldn't find it using Google. Also, just clarifying, is there any chance that the factor of 1/2pi is being missed in the previous pair. The reason I'm clarifying is that I see 1/2pi factor in the following related FT pair: $f_{1}(t) f_{2}(t) \stackrel{F T}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{2 \pi} F_{1}(\omega) * F_{2}(\omega)$

Comment: Yeah, that is right. The $2\pi$ depends on how you define the FT. some people don't put $2\pi$ there (and then you get $2\pi$ in other places) this is why md2perpe said "Modulo some constant factor"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'm using this definition of FT: Fourier transform formula: $\mathscr{F}\{f(x)\}=\mathcal{F}(\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{j \alpha x} d x$. Do I get the factor of 1/2pi?

Comment: I don't remember, and too busy to check atm. You should try some examples and see if it works out